# How to pack/unpack(read) idx files?

Tags: java

Note: Using java.
I've been searching almost all day on a way to pack an idx file. I only found something on another website & they told me to rip it from something called an RSPS?...

I just want to pack text files, models, images & if possible a directory containing java files.

I'm trying to build a packed/smaller cache for my game & this is the most i've ever been stuck.

Comment: And which idx format would this be? "idx" is about the most generic extension for index files, there is no single thing that is "the" idx file format.

Comment: an idx for images, one for models, & if possible one for java files.
ex: sprites.idx, models.idk, interfaces.idx <text files, javafiles.idx

Comment: no I mean "idx" according to which specification? Otherwise an idx file is nothing, just an arbitrary packing with an arbitrary packing that your packer and unpacker agree on, and you can use whatever you like. You'll need to provide more details like whether you'll need to fetching data without doing a full unpack into memory, or whether it needs to be a random bag or ordered sequences, whether it needs to do compression or not, whether it's a data resource or communicable, etc. If you just want to pack, use zip. Done.

Comment: I didn't realize it was like that, I'm trying to pack it into an idx file that the data can be read without unpacking it ex: an image i can still use drawImage to display the image on my client. So when i call for an object inside the idx file it can be read. The point of me doing this is to pack my cache so it's harder for other to obtain my models & sprites. & can't edit them to change game play client sided.

Comment: a .tar.gz package might be the easiest then. Most programming languages can work with tgz data (rename it to "idx", the packer/unpacker doesn't care =). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402598/extract-a-tar-gz-file-in-java-jsp covers two ways to extract, option 2 being far more manageable than option 1 (packing is about as easy)

Comment: meh, not here for the rep, but I can turn it into an answer and you can flag it as the right one =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no true "idx" spec, it's more a generic file extension for files that have been packed with any number of different packing algorithms for which an unpacking algorithm exists. As long as your packer and unpacker agree, you can rename an archive to "idx" and it's right.

If you have no specific criteria for packing, like fetching data without doing a full unpack into memory, o it needs to be a random bag or ordered sequences, whether it needs to do compression or not, whether it's a data resource or communicable, etc. you can actually just use something like zip and done.

A common packer choice is the "gzipped tarbal", which gives use the .tar.gz file extension. Most programming languages can work with tgz data (rename it to "idx", the packer/unpacker doesn't care =), for java the second answer in [Extract a .tar.gz file in java (JSP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402598/extract-a-tar-gz-file-in-java-jsp) covers a pretty easy way to do unpacking a tgz file in Java, the opposite direction should be relatively easy to find given what the unpacking looks like.