# Extract .tar.gz file in Build.scala (without external libraries)

Tags: scala, sbt, gzip, tar

There are a lot of questions about extracting `.tar.gz` files in Java/Scala but all of them involve using some library to [extract the tar file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17079034/691859). `GZIPInputStream` is part of Java SE but I don't know of a way to extract tarballs using Java SE.

As far as I can tell, when I'm in `Build.scala` I can't use the dependencies I'm pulling in. But I need to extract this `tar.gz` file. How can I do that without relying on external libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbt build files are recursive; you can specify library dependencies for the build file in `project/project/Build.scala` or `project/build.sbt`.

For example

**project/build.properties**:

```
sbt.version=0.13.7
```

**project/build.sbt**:

```
libraryDependencies += "de.sciss" % "model_2.10" % "0.3.2"
```

And then you'll be able to use that library in **./build.sbt**:

```
lazy val foo = de.sciss.model.Change(1, 2) // from the library

name := foo.toString
```

Test: `sbt name`

Comment: I guess this works, and thanks for reminding me of this, but I was hoping of a way to do it using just standard libraries. If there isn't a way to do it with just standard libraries though, I'll just use the apache commons `TarArchiveInputStream` through your method here.

Comment: if you are on a *nix platform, you could probably just invoke a shell command for un-tar.

Comment: Yeah, I considered it, but I want to make sure that I build something that'd work on Windows if we ever open source our work. :)